# Multiple Sites and Authentications with one Database

Tags: security, express, nginx, arangodb

This may be a simple question, but it's my first time setting-up a website this way and I need some advice please.

**The setup:**

- I have two websites:  WS1 & WS2, each with different domainnames.
  They both point to the same IP using nginx server blocks and SSL is
  setup for each domain name. I will be using Express.js with ArangoDB (where I can
  add additional databases in ArangoDB to split-up the two sites in the
  backend if necessary)

**The problem:**

- Sometimes these two sites will be accessing the same info from the database and I would
  prefer  NOT having to duplicate the data but they will have different
  authentications. Each site will have different account
  authentications and page restrictions for each member of each site.

**The question:**

- How would I set this up to ensure security, so that one account
  doesn't get access to  any other site? Do I need two separate frameworks in each server block? Should I create two databases? Best recommendations pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your authorization framework.

*Authentication* identifies who is accessing your site, and part of that identity is the user, the company/domain, and the role/group they belong to.

*Authorization* is the description of what that user, company/domain, or role/group is allowed to access.

You probably know about cookies and username/passwords for the user identification. The user is stored in the database and mapped to the company/domain they belong to. and the user is also mapped to the role/group they belong to.

`select userID, company from users where username = ?, $username`

`select group from groups where userID = ?, $userID`

Some of the records in the database are probably scoped to a single domain/company and others to a role/group. You add the domain/company or role/group as a column on the database, and use it in your query.

`select content from companyPages where company = ?`

or

`select content from groupPages where group in (select group from groups where userID = ?))`

You can have users from multiple companies/domains using the same groups too.

And putting it together:

`Select content from pages WHERE
    group in (select group from groups where userID= ?)
    AND company = (select company from users where userID=?);`

Basically you have to define your authorization scheme and map it to your data model.

Comment: Is there away that authenticated users on Website1 could access data from Website2 (if they weren't authorized on WS2)  simply because they are on the same database?

Comment: Yes. If you don't include the Website1 in the query. But if your queries are smart, and you don't have sql injection, this is a normal pattern. Again, the construction of your queries and datamodel decides the security.

Comment: I see. Thanks! So, I can use a single database then... And would you recommend setting-up two separate frameworks for each site on each block? Or a single framework?

Comment: One is fine. Even if you have two, you still have to include Website1 or Website2 in the query. Setting up two doesn't really buy you anything for security.

Comment: As you can tell, i'm new to all this, so appreciate that you took the time to explain. Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if you have more questions.